# How to take integer input from user in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, input, integer, null-safety

i am new in dart and just want to know how to take integer input from user in dart with null safety. i found out a way to take number input from dart which is:

```
String? chossenNumber =  stdin. readLineSync();
   if(chossenNumber !=null)
   {
     int number = int.parse(chossenNumber);
   }
```

but i am unable to use number variable outside of the scope. Please tell me a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable at the top of the class and initialize it here so you will be able to use it everywhere in the class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution of it very simple just take input of number as String i.e

```
String? chossenNumber =  stdin. readLineSync();
```

and when you want to use this variable parse it to the 'int' i.e

```
if(int.parse(chossenNumber) <100)
{
print("Your Statement");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable at the top of the class

```
var name,age;

print('Enter Your Age : ');

age=int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!) ;

print(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving `chosenNumber` for the `stdin`

```
String? chosenNumber =  stdin.readLineSync();
```

You can declare `number` at the top of the method as a nullable `integer`, for example:

```
int? number;
```

Then after your check, you can initialize `number`

```
if (chosenNumber != null) {
  number = int.parse(chosenNumber);
}
```

This way you will have access to `number` outside the `if` scope

Summary

```
String? chosenNumber =  stdin.readLineSync();

int? number;

if (chosenNumber != null) {
  number = int.parse(chosenNumber);
}

print(number); // number is accessible here
number = 19; // and here
```